# Why does executing a scalar function result in a "create function" operation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I needed to trim a number of strings in a select statement, so instead of repeating multiple ltrim(rtrim(' the string ') calls, I created a simple trim function as follows:

```
create function dbo.trim(@String varchar(max))
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
    return rtrim(ltrim(@String))
end
go
```

However, during the execution of my select (which invokes the function multiple times) I run the following select in a different window as sa:

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

and observe the following

```
TEXT    session_id  status  command cpu_time    total_elapsed_time
------------------------------------------------------------------    
**      99          running SELECT  12045       12388
```

where the first column (replaced by ** above for readability) contains the following:

```
create function dbo.trim(@String varchar(max))
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
    return rtrim(ltrim(@String))
end
```

Am I correctly interpreting this to mean that upon calling the trim function that SQL Server actually calls a create?

As you can see from the table above, the execution time is rather long and in some cases I've found the create operation to outright hang thus blocking the completion of the select and further write operations on the database such that I've had to kill the operation.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks!
Pab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correctly interpreting this to mean that upon calling the trim
>   function that SQL Server actually calls a create?

No, SQL Server just shows you the full text of the SQL Module - which includes the `CREATE`. You can use `statement_start_offset` and `statement_end_offset` [to see the statement actually being executed](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1811/how-to-isolate-the-current-running-commands-in-sql-server/).

SideNote: You're better off not using scalar UDFs for something trivial like a `TRIM` function. These have well known performance problems. See [Converting A Scalar User Defined Function To A Inline Table Valued Function](http://jahaines.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/converting-scalar-user-defined-function.html) for an alternative approach if this is worth encapsulating in a function at all.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I suspected that might be the case. I little more googling and I see what you mean. As for the performance problems, I guess I'm getting a taste of them first hand. I'll simply use the rtrim(ltrim(' the string')) approach.